# return max sum of consecutive groups of numbers in excel

Tags: excel

I have an Excel file with dynamic range that I want to use for trading statement, I'm trying to calculate the maximum consecutive loss/profit (not maximally or counting), the method I used was to have an auxiliary column that I use to calculate consecutive loss but the problem I have is that since my file has a dynamic range, I have to apply the the consecutive loss calculation formula to lots of cells (to avoid a situation where I have data that is not considered in max consecutive loss), this causes my file to run slow,

[here is the file](https://1drv.ms/x/s!Aodb5YWsdDA6jchvy_hDCZ0X_cUVsA?e=CAkPuX)

Thank you for help.

I was wondering if there was a better way for solving this issue.

Comment: Surely nobody here will open some random excel (?) file someone posted ... Describe your problem, sampledata and attempts to solve your issue within this post ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try combination of few lambda functions.

```
=LET(p,DROP(REDUCE(1,B4:B42,LAMBDA(a,x,VSTACK(a,IF(x=0,MAX(a)+1,MAX(a))))),1),q,UNIQUE(p),MAX(MAP(q,LAMBDA(z,SUM(FILTER(B4:B42,p=z))))))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I don't particularly want to open the file, but I imagine it would be something like this for profit:

```
=LET(data,A2:INDEX(A:A,COUNTA(A:A)),MAX(SCAN(0,data,LAMBDA(a,c,IF(c<=0,0,a+c)))))
```

[image]

and similarly for loss.